# Localhost not working Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: apache, localhost

I'm setting up localhost and "localhost" by itself does print

## It works!

But when trying to access  "http://localhost/Users/Marcel/Sites/hello.html" it outputs the 404 not found error. I followed this https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083﻿.

Comment: Just check if you have the set correct permissions on the hello.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must install a Web Server like **MAMP**, and follow this easy procedure:

- Put your files in the directory Applications/MAMP/htdocs
- Open MAMP
- Configure a port to listen HTTP (like 8080)
- Start MAMP
- Open browser and go to http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/FileName.extension